A Strange Way to Blow Teruah
I recall learning an outlier Rabbinic opinion that the correct way to blow teruah is actually by shaking the shofar with the hands. I saw it demonstrated as a child. What is the source for this opinion?

All traditional shofar sounds that I know of involve only the internal breathing apparatus. I suspect this is a "trick" to approximate some of those sounds by someone who has difficulty controlling it with his lungs.
